# Fetch username and user ID from another table in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have created a model and controller where i fetch a list of users reviews and I want to show their `username` and `ID` in my view which are stored in another table called `users`, however I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to do so.

**This is my model**

```
public function fetch_company_reviews($id = NULL) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('customer_company_reviews_company_id', $id);
    $this->db->from('customer_company_reviews');
    $this->db->order_by('customer_company_reviews_id', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return $query->result();
    }

}
```

**This is my controller**

```
public function index($id = NULL)
{
    $id = $this->input->get('id'); 
    $data['company_info'] = $this->Company_model->fetch_company($id);
    $data['company_reviews'] = $this->Company_model->fetch_company_reviews($id);
    $get = $data['company_info'];
    $this->load->view('includes/header');
    $this->load->view('company/company_index', $data);
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
```

**This is my view**

```
<?php foreach ($company_reviews as $review) { ?>
<div class="review-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <h4><?= $review->customer_company_reviews_title; ?></h4>
      <?= $review->customer_company_reviews_comment; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Table structure `users`**

```
id | username
-------------
 1 | admin
```

**Table structure `customer_company_reviews`**

```
cu...reviews_id | cu...reviews_author | cu...reviews_title
---------------------------------------------------------
 1              | 1                  | Some title
```

How can i fetch and access `id` and `username` from `users`-table where `customer_company_reviews_author`-row is storing the user ID in my review table `(customer_company_reviews)` and then finally show it in my view as a variable inside my `foreach` loop?

Comment: not clear what are you asking for, show your table structure

Comment: i think you have to use join

Comment: Does your first table has foreign key of user table like user_id?

Comment: @PHPExpert it's "id".

Comment: @PathikVejani updated with relevant table structure and what do you mean by "join"?

Comment: is `reviews_author` = `users.id`?

Comment: @PathikVejani I see how that can be confusing, but yep... It is.

Comment: friend ,you have to add a field named review_reference_id in user table. then only you can join the result.add a field for review id reference in user table and look the code i gave below.surely help you

Comment: From where r u getting  `<?= $review->customer_company_reviews_comment; ?>` in your view file  ? because i see no column named `customer_company_reviews_comment` in your table `customer_company_reviews`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I did not include the whole table, only relevant rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join with User table as below

```
$this->db->select('customer_company_reviews.* ,users.*');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = customer_company_reviews.customer_company_reviews_author');
$this->db->where('customer_company_reviews_company_id', $id);
$this->db->from('customer_company_reviews');
$this->db->order_by('customer_company_reviews_id', 'desc');
$this->db->limit(1);
```

use `*` from both the tables as we want both id and username from user table.

Answer (score 1):

Friend You can easily fetch the result by using join.I wil help you

In Model

```
public function fetch_company_reviews($id = NULL) 
{       
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('customer_company_reviews');
    $this->db->join('users', 'customer_company_reviews.customer_company_reviews_company_id = users.reference_review_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('customer_company_reviews_company_id', $id);
    $this->db->order_by('customer_company_reviews_id', 'desc');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```